# how to remove item from array list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
data class RideDate(var enddate: String? = null,var startdate: String? = null) 



 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
var listOfRideDate = mutableListOf<RideDate>();
val date1 = RideDate()
date1.startdate = "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000"
date1.enddate = "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"
listOfRideDate.add(date1)

val date2 = RideDate()
date2.startdate = "2020-01-20 00:00:00 +0000"
date2.enddate = "2020-02-20 00:00:00 +0000"
listOfRideDate.add(date2)

val date3 = RideDate()
date3.startdate = "2020-03-20 00:00:00 +0000"
date3.enddate = "2020-03-20 00:00:00 +0000"
listOfRideDate.add(date3)

val date4 = RideDate()
date4.startdate = "2020-04-20 00:00:00 +0000"
date4.enddate = "2020-04-20 00:00:00 +0000"
listOfRideDate.add(date4)

val date5 = RideDate()
date5.startdate = "2020-11-20 00:00:00 +0000"
date5.enddate = "2020-11-20 00:00:00 +0000"
listOfRideDate.add(date5)


for (i in 0..listOfRideDate.size -1) {
    // we have to remove 2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000 and 2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000  from list 
    println(listOfRideDate.get(i).startdate + " and " + listOfRideDate.get(i).enddate)
}
```

}

This is my data class and the main method I have added item RideDate of startDate and endDate 
manually  I want  delete item dynamically if data contains 
   date1.startdate = "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000"
    date1.enddate = "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"

so that I can ignore it please help me how to delete the item from array list in kotlin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [removeAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html) to remove element from original list if it matches the predicate.

```kotlin
listOfRideDate.removeAll {
    it.startdate == "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000" && it.enddate == "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"
}
```

Or you can [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) by creating a new list with filtered items as suggested by Johann Kexel

```kotlin
val filtertedList = listOfRideDate.filter {
    it.startdate == "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000" && it.enddate == "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
loop@ for (i in 0 until listOfRideDate.size) {
        // we have to remove 2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000 and 2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000  from list
        if (listOfRideDate.get(i).startdate == "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000" &&  listOfRideDate.get(i).enddate == "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"){
            listOfRideDate.removeAt(i)
            break@loop
        }
    }
```

or

```
listOfRideDate.removeIf {
     it.startdate == "2018-11-05 00:00:00 +0000" &&  it.enddate == "2018-11-06 23:59:59 +0000"
}
```

Comment: its show Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4

Comment: you cannot remove something within a loop.
If you want to change your current list, you have to first save your element(s) within the loop and then use `remove(element)` or `removeAll(elements)`  on the collection (Or of course also `removeAt(index)`) outside the loop

Comment: No, you can, Just need to stop for loop.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir multiple objects may not be filtered, indexing is done several times so may slow down the performance

Comment: Right, you can remove one item

Comment: Sure you can do this, if you only want to remove one element.

Comment: @JohannKexel yup

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` in your case

```
val filtertedList = listOfRideDate.filter { element -> someLogik(element)}
```

Refer also to the following page

[Filtering Kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-filtering.html)

Comment: can you please help me where I will add this code I am really new in this function what condition and how I will apply here someLogik(element)

Comment: how to apply a filter for the start date and end date please help me in this?

Comment: @MARSH do you want to remove element from original list or want to create a new filtered one?

Comment: `someLogik` was just an example and symbolizes a function which returns a Boolean and which you can define on yourself. For example `fun nonNull(element:RideDate) = element != null` . You can use this filtering logic instead or after your foreach loop.