# How delete Item from ArrayList in Firestore using Koltin

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete one item from the `animeId`. For example, if I need to remove the `animeId[5]` or I want to remove the item that the value is equal `5114`, how can I do that? I alredy learned how I remove item like the entire `animeId`but not just one item.
Here's an print how the database is organized:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove item from array list in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183570/how-to-remove-item-from-array-list-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating some fields of a document, use the update() method.

If you want to remove a specific item from an Arraylist, you can use a call to:

`.update("arrayfield", FieldValue.arrayRemove("itemtoremove"))`

For example if you have an arraylist that contains three items as “abc”, “efg”, “xyz”.
And if you want to remove specific item called “efg” from an arraylist you should use a call to:

`.update("arrayfield", FieldValue.arrayRemove("efg"))`

Please also take a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879267) which explains clearly on
how to remove specific items from the array list in the firestore using kotlin.